# How can I figure out what line of Python code is generating a PendingDeprecationWarning?

Tags: python-3.x, deprecated, freezegun

I have a set of Python 3 unittests, which, when executed with this command line:

```
python3 -m unittest discover -f -v
```

...are generating a **PendingDeprecationWarning**:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py:32:
    PendingDeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
```

Is there an easy way for me to trace which peice of code is ultimately using `imp.py`, perhaps by turning on some form of stack tracing? I have narrowed it down somewhat; it seems to only be triggered when I use [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun). However, freezegun itself doesn't seem to use **imp**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When invoking python on the command line, pass the option `-Werror` to it. This will turn all warnings into errors, and when the warning/error doesn't get handled, it will display a traceback that will give you line numbers and source files for each step that let to the warning/error.

Comment: Perfect! That helped me determine that it was the dependent library `six`.

Comment: FWIW, this was the bug: https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/issue/112/sixmovesreload_module-uses-deprecated-imp